# How can I redirect to an external url in zend

Tags: zend-framework, url, redirect

I'm trying to create links such as /redirector/http://www.google.co.uk so that it runs a custom redirect action which records link usage. I've set up the router with the code below,

```
routes.redirector.route = /redirector/:url
routes.redirector.defaults.module = default
routes.redirector.defaults.controller = index
routes.redirector.defaults.action = redirector
```

and am using this within my IndexController, but can't get it working. I think it's because of the double forward slash within the url to forward to. Can someone provide me with a solution without removing the 'http://' so that this will work in zend?

```
    public function redirectorAction() {          
        $this->_redirector->gotoUrl($this->getRequest()->getParam('url'));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default route class separates paths into components split by the /, so :url will never be the full ending url. What you can do instead, is use the Regex router, which you can define to match the full request uri and map to the url parameter.

```
routes.redirector.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.redirector.route = "redirector/(.*)"
routes.redirector.defaults.module = default
routes.redirector.defaults.controller = index
routes.redirector.defaults.action = redirector
routes.redirector.map.1 = "url"
```

Comment: Hi andy, I've copied and pasted it into my routes.ini, but it has stopped my site from working. Any clue as to why?

Comment: It looks like it needed double quotes around routes.redirector.route, many thanks Andy!